# How to remove the list from an array using angular +

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7

I am using the checkbox to get the list of 
below is the data:

```
data:[{ email: "email1" }, { email: "email2" }, { email: "email3" }, { email: 'email4' }]
```

**html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <th></th>
     <th></th>
   </thead>  
   <tbody>
     <td *ngFor="let x of collection;">              
         <input type="checkbox" (change)="checkEmails($event,x)" />
     </td>
     <td>{{x.email}}</td>
   </tbody>
<table>
```

**.ts file**

```
public groupList: any = [];
checkEmails(event, email) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      if (this.groupList.length == 0) {
        this.groupList.push(email);
      }
      else {
        this.groupList.push(email);
      }
      console.log("bulkData", this.groupList);
    }
  }
```

Now the list is adding into an array..

But when deselecting the checkbox I want to remove the list from an array.
Can anybody help me??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use **splice** function

```
checkEmails(event, email) {
if (event.target.checked) {
  this.groupList.push(email);
  console.log("bulkData", this.groupList);
} else {
  for(var i = 0 ; i < this.groupList.length; i++) {
    if(this.groupList[i].email == email.email) {
      this.groupList.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log("bulkData1", this.groupList);
}
```

}

Working Example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-splice

For more clarification : https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/